# xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp, xampp

When I try to start my `xampp` I get these errors:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
ok.
```

How can I solve this problem with `xampplib` and how can I get the `xampp` to work?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It seems that your xampp instance is complaining about lack of `netstat` command.

`netstat` is a part of `net-tools` package, so run this command to install netstat:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Then try to start your `xampp` again, it should work now.

Comment: You are the LORD!

Comment: Thanks Man :)  . Helped me.